# Can servers block curl requests specifically?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Generally speaking, is it possible for a server to block a PHP cURL request?

I've been making cURL requests every 15 minutes to a certain public-facing URL for about 6-8 months.  Suddenly the other day it stopped working, and the URL started returning an empty string.

When I hit the URL in a browser or with a python get request, it returns the expected data.

I decided to try hitting the same URL with a file_get_contents() function in PHP, and that works as expected as well.

Since I found a bandaid solution for now, is there any difference between the default headers that cURL sends vs file_get_contents() that would allow one request to be blocked and the other to get through?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your cURL request, please include that code above

Comment: use proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

> Generally speaking, is it possible for a server to block a PHP cURL
>   request?

Sort of. The server can block requests if your user agent string looks like it comes from curl. Try using the `-A` option to set a custom user agent string.

```
curl -A "Foo/1.1" <url>
```

Edit: Oops I see you said "from PHP", so just set the CURLOPT_USERAGENT option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Foo/1.1');
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of websites block you based on user agent. Best workaround that I can think of is to simply open up your developer console in Chrome, and click on network tab. Go to the URL of the website that you are trying to access and find the request that gets data that you need. Right click on that request and copy it as cURL. It will have all the headers that your browser is sending.

If you add all of those headers, to your cURL request in php, web-server will not be able to tell the difference between request from your curl and your browser's.

You will need to update those headers once every couple years (some websites try to forbid old versions of firefox or chrome which bots have been abusing for years).

Comment: Aha, great stuff!  I've never really used Chrome's developer tools, I'm always in FF and/or Safari.  I copied the request as cURL and sure enough it worked.  I made a few tweaks in my headers and the original cURL request works as expected now.

I think you're right — it was probably just the user agent that was getting me.  Still strange that a php file_get_contents() request will successfully pull the URL and the original cURL request won't anymore.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ryes31 If you are bombarding that website with requests(especially if that website does not get much user traffic) , I strongly suggest implementing an array of about 5-10 possible headers and randomly picking one for your requests. That way it will look like you are a small network with a bunch of different distinct users performing requests...

Answer (score 1):

Forget curl. Think about it from the perspective of an HTTP request. All the server sees is that. If your curl request contains something (user agent header for instance) that the server can use to filter out requests, it can use this to reject those requests.